# How can I get the row count of a table that is in a different database from where the query is run?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm trying to get the number of rows in a table that is located in a different database from where this query is run. For my example below I have a database named `TestDB` with a table in it named `TestTable2` that I'm trying to get the number of rows. Here is the query that works to get the row counts for all tables in the database:

```
SELECT p.[rows] AS [Num_Rows]
     , OBJECT_NAME(i.OBJECT_ID) AS [Table_Name]
FROM TestDb.sys.indexes AS i
    INNER JOIN TestDb.sys.partitions AS p 
        ON p.OBJECT_ID = i.OBJECT_ID 
       AND p.index_id = i.index_id
    INNER JOIN TestDb.sys.allocation_units AS a 
        ON a.container_id = p.partition_id
    INNER JOIN TestDb.sys.tables AS t 
        ON i.OBJECT_ID = t.OBJECT_ID
WHERE i.type <= 1
  AND a.type = 1
  AND t.type = 'U'
  AND t.is_ms_shipped = 0
```

But when I try to add a filter to the where clause so it only returns the table I'm interested in, the query no longer returns any results:

```
  AND OBJECT_NAME(i.OBJECT_ID) = 'TestTable2'
```

I can see the `TestTable2` table in the results from the first query, but when I add that last filter, nothing is returned. When I run this same query with the added filter directly from the `TestDb` database, it runs without issue! What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try query like this

```
select t.name, i.rows from yourdatabase.sys.tables t
inner join yourdatabase.sys.sysindexes i
on t.object_id = i.id
where i.indid < 2
and t.name = 'yourtable'
```

Not sure I understood your question correctly though